# Funcion sumar numero

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguien puede decirme como hacer una función asignada a un botón que coja un número dentro del DOM, le sume X y reemplace el viejo numero por el nuevo?

He probado con esto.

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton"); //variable de boton para incrementar valor
var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;  //variable del numero en el DOM

boton.addEventListener("click", boton);        

function lvl1cash() {                             
  var result = numero++;                               //variable con el resultado
  document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = result; //Muestra resultado de la funcion en DOM
}
```

```html
<h3 id="numero">1</h3>
<button id="boton" value="Boton" onclick="boton">SUMAR</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que para capturar el valor de un elemento de formulario se usa `.value`, pero cuando el elemento es un elemento diferente (como en este caso que es un `<h3>`) se debe usar `.innerHTML` para capturar su contenido, luego de hacer eso en el `addEventListener` debes indicar la función que se va a ejecutar al hacer click en el botón, así:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton"); //variable de boton para incrementar valor

var numero = document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML; //variable del numero en el DOM

boton.addEventListener("click", lvl1cash);        

function lvl1cash() {
  var result = ++numero;                               //variable con el resultado
  document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = result; //Muestra resultado de la funcion en DOM
}
```

```html
<h3 id="numero">1</h3>
<button id="boton" value="Boton" onclick="boton">SUMAR</button>
```

Comment: Solucionado, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo también con jQuery, siendo bastante más amigable:

```js
// variable de boton para incrementar valor
var $boton = $("#boton");
// variable del numero en el DOM
var $numero = $("#numero").text();


$boton.on("click", lvl1cash);

function lvl1cash() {
  // Muestra resultado de la funcion en DOM
  $("#numero").text(++$numero);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="numero">1</h3>
<button id="boton" value="Boton">SUMAR</button>
```